# How do I fixed divs from overlapping centered, static div on browser resize?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a two columned layout with a sidebar that always stays on the left side of the page with a main content area that is centered, and when the window is resized, the centered content will eventually bump up against the nav bar, but never move any further left than where it is when they touch (which would be left: 150px).

Can someone help me out?

Here is the CSS:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body,td,th {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 10000px;
    background-color: #D61D21;
    text-align: right;
}

#nav a:link {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#main {
    width: 810px;
    height: 810px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

and here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Nick Passaro Designs</title>
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="nav">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="assets/marklogo.jpg" width="150" height="97" border="0" alt="Nick Passaro Designs"></a>
        <p><a href="portfolio.php">PORTFOLIO</a> &nbsp;</p>
        <p><a href="logos.php">LOGOS</a> &nbsp;</p>
        <p><a href="print.php">PRINT</a> &nbsp;</p>
        <p><a href="web.php">WEB DESIGN</a> &nbsp;</p>
        <p><a href="photography.php">PHOTOGRAPHY</a> &nbsp;</p>
        <p><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a> &nbsp;</p>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        ENTER CONTENT HERE
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Nick Passaro Designs</title>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="assets/marklogo.jpg" width="150" height="97" border="0" alt="Nick Passaro Designs"></a>
        <p><a href="portfolio.php">PORTFOLIO</a> &nbsp;</p>
        <p><a href="logos.php">LOGOS</a> &nbsp;</p>
        <p><a href="print.php">PRINT</a> &nbsp;</p>
        <p><a href="web.php">WEB DESIGN</a> &nbsp;</p>
        <p><a href="photography.php">PHOTOGRAPHY</a> &nbsp;</p>
        <p><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a> &nbsp;</p>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="main">
            ENTER CONTENT HERE
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    margin-left: 150px;
}
```

What you do is create a wrapper div around your main div and make that wrapper div have a left-margin of 150px so that it's side by side with the nav bar.  Now all your resizes inside the main div should be limited to within the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

A neat little trick I just learned is making your #content position: relative; and then make all child elements inside it position: absolute; that way all child elements are absolute to your content area and the content will resize to any resolution.  Saves me so loads of time and i can't believe how much time I used to waste laying dynamic sites out.

Hope this does something for you.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what i'm looking for.  I've done that before, and it doesn't allow the objects inside #content to change how they are positioned relative to each other.  I need #nav to always be stuck to the far left side of the screen and i need #content to be centered until they touch, but can't have them as children of an encompassing div.